# Make a query spring jpa for inner class

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

let assume I have struct like this:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Entity
  public static class ClientCase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
  }
}
```

How can I make a query to find client case by id?

I tried this:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM ClientCase c WHERE c.id = :id")
Optional<ClientCase> findById(Long id);
```

but I get:

aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'ClientCase'